# The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager #2

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, database, entity-framework

I get the problem in the screenshot:
[image: problem]

Here is the code at the beginning of the program:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        BlackoutDates();

        variables.date = Convert.ToDateTime(MainCalendar.DisplayDate);
        DateOutput.Content = MainCalendar.DisplayDate.DayOfWeek + ", " + MainCalendar.DisplayDate.ToShortDateString();



    }

    //initialises entities
    WpfApplication7.AllensCroftEntities1 allensCroftEntities1 = new WpfApplication7.AllensCroftEntities1();
    private Booking ObjectIndex;
```

Here is the code when the window is loaded

```
 private void Bookings_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


       WpfApplication7.AllensCroftEntities1 allensCroftEntities1 = new WpfApplication7.AllensCroftEntities1();
        // Load data into Rooms.
        var roomsViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("roomsViewSource")));
        var roomsQuery = this.GetRoomsQuery(allensCroftEntities1);
        roomsViewSource.Source = roomsQuery.Execute(MergeOption.AppendOnly);

    }
```

Here is the code for the delete button which causes the error:

```
 private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        //prevents user trying to delete nothing/unselected row
        if (ObjectIndex == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot delete the blank entry");
        }
        else
        {

            //deletes object from dataset, saves it and outputs a message
            allensCroftEntities1.DeleteObject(ObjectIndex);

            allensCroftEntities1.SaveChanges();
            MessageBox.Show("Booking Deleted");
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for the object index:

```
   private void listrow_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        //outputs index of the selected room
        ObjectIndex = listrow.SelectedItem as Booking;
    }
```

EDIT,

i tried

```
 allensCroftEntities1.Attach(ObjectIndex);
```

[image: attach]

EDIT,

When i comment out the entities in the bookings loaded event, I get this error, this code used to work fine, but i dont know why all of these problems are occurring.

[image: nullable]

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try attaching entity to the context first:

```
allensCroftEntities1.Attach(ObjectIndex);
allensCroftEntities1.DeleteObject(ObjectIndex);
```

Or use context declared in class scope instead of local one within `Bookings_Loaded` event handler by deleting that line:

```
WpfApplication7.AllensCroftEntities1 allensCroftEntities1 = new WpfApplication7.AllensCroftEntities1();
```

Comment: i had already done that, see the code under the main window section

Comment: Yes, you've declared context in class-scope, but there is another local variable with the same name within `Bookings_Loaded`

Comment: i tried, another error, see latest edit, this used to work but i dont know why id doesnt any more

Comment: The last one looks like non-EF connected.

Comment: ill uncomment that entity decaration

Comment: fixed the problem, it was the binding on the calendar causing the problem